# Virt-manager "Unable to complete install: 'Requested operation is not valid: network 'default' is not active'"

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, virt-manager

I have just instaled `virt-manager` on Arch Linux, I've gone through all of the steps of creating a VM, but when I click on "Finish" on step 5/5 I get two pop-up dialogs:

Unable to complete install: 'Requested operation is not valid: network 'default' is not active'

Details:

```
Unable to complete install: 'Requested operation is not valid: network 'default' is not active'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvm.py", line 2008, in _do_async_install
    installer.start_install(guest, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 695, in start_install
    domain = self._create_guest(
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 637, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(initial_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 4408, in createXML
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: Requested operation is not valid: network 'default' is not active
```

and Could not start virtual network 'default': Unable to create bridge virbr0: Package not installed

Details:

```
Could not start virtual network 'default': Unable to create bridge virbr0: Package not installed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/device/netlist.py", line 208, in _check_network_is_running
    netobj.start()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/network.py", line 69, in start
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3474, in create
    raise libvirtError('virNetworkCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: Unable to create bridge virbr0: Package not installed
```

I saw that is said "package not installed" after `virbr0`, so I tried:
`$ sudo pacman -Syu virbr0` - not found
`$ yay -Syu virbr0` - also not found

Comment: Please post the entire list of packages you installed, including those for qemu. I think you missed libvirt.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already solved. In general, you should check the libvirt networks with the following command:

```
virsh net-list
```